# add_commas function not working with 10000 but does 1000

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone have ideas why my commas are not adding now I have reached into the 10,000 but was OK in the 1,000's?

```
function add_commas(number) {
    if (number.length > 3) {
        var mod = number.length % 3;
        var output = (mod > 0 ? (number.substring(0,mod)) : '');
        for (i=0 ; i < Math.floor(number.length / 3); i++) {
            if ((mod == 0) && (i == 0)) {
                output += number.substring(mod+ 3 * i, mod + 3 * i + 3);
            } else {
                output+= ',' + number.substring(mod + 3 * i, mod + 3 * i + 3);
            }
        }
            return (output);
        } else {
            return number;
    }
}
```

I still use this for some values which are in the 1,000's so need it to still work with that but little lost what to do for the higher values?

Comment: Was going to say, if it's PHP you can just use http://php.net/number-format ...

Comment: haha its rather old, thought would check the page as not checked for a few years and noticed was not working correctly.... was still using mysql and was broken so had to update the connection and queries to use mysqli pdo haha

Comment: Think that was the was i got it to work when server was on an oldder version of PHP so ill scrap that then lol

Comment: Oh my bad its not JS, sorry.... been a long day!! its JS

Comment: @James ------------^^ very long day :)

Comment: 6:30am start > 2.5hr drive to clients 9hrs there, 2hr drive back, installed new router at grandparents which had issues with ISP so took an hour, got home and on another 8/9hr stint coding lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function number_format(number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep) {
  number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '')
  var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number
  var prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals)
  var sep = (typeof thousandsSep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousandsSep
  var dec = (typeof decPoint === 'undefined') ? '.' : decPoint
  var s = ''

  var toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
    var k = Math.pow(10, prec)
    return '' + (Math.round(n * k) / k)
      .toFixed(prec)
  }

  // @todo: for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
  s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.')
  if (s[0].length > 3) {
    s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep)
  }
  if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
    s[1] = s[1] || ''
    s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0')
  }

  return s.join(dec)
}

number_format(100) => 100
number_format(1000) => 1,000
number_format(10000) => 10,000
```

Google can be your friend :) [original](http://locutus.io/php/strings/number_format/)

Comment: Google can be and i always say... when i doubt google it out which is what i was just about to do but also dealing with some server issues at the same time haha ill give it a try now.

Comment: yep worked a treat, thanks for googling and helping me quickly while im multi-tasking haha thanks again mate.

Comment: If you can, better to use library that are well tested and has community behind it. You can tons of them. Here is the one [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/)

Comment: @James you are welcome. I just saw your question when it was flagged as `PHP`, so first thing I thought about was `number_format` function. And then I wondered, if something like that exists in JS. Also I want to thank you, because I haven't know that one too :)

Comment: haha no worries, glad could of been some help even though i wasn't much of  helpful hand :) take care buddy and thanks again.